# Java - For-loop with two conditions does not work as expected

Tags: java, exception, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have coded two for-loops which should fill a GridBagLayout. Somehow the second condition does not come to operation and therefore I get an exception.

So basically what the program does: It gets the data from a MySQL Server and lists it in a GridBagLayout. Therefore I get the lenght of the row by using `rs.lenght` and `rs.getRow()`. Than I copy it to `lenghtCounter` for the inner for-loop(with the x variable). The inner for-loop should be executed after 3 cycles OR if lenghtCounter is equal to 0. I see in the console that the counter works and gets down to 0 as expected but the for-loop does not break. Instead it continues and gives me an exception.

Here is the code:

```
        try {
            ResultSet rs = MySQL.getStatement().executeQuery(
                    "select * from obj_house");
            rs.last();
            int lenghtCounter = rs.getRow();
            int lenght = lenghtCounter;
            rs.first();
            System.out.println(lenghtCounter + " " + (lenght / 3));

            for (int y = 0; y <= (lenght / 3); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 3 || lenghtCounter==0; x++) {
                    System.out.println("ID " + lenghtCounter);

                    JButton street = new JButton("Strasse: " + rs.getString(5));

                    gbcOut.gridx = x;
                    gbcOut.gridy = y;
                    panelBottom.add(street, gbcOut);

                    System.out.println("X: " + x);
                    System.out.println("Y: " + y);
                    rs.next();
                    lenghtCounter--;
                    System.out.println("lenght: " + lenghtCounter);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can you update your question with the error stacktrace?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

Answer (score 3):

Try with the test :

```
x < 3 && lenghtCounter>0
```

Comment: Thanks! :) This works perfect. Now I see the mistake. I thought it is the condition to terminate the operation. But it is the condition to continue the operation. Is that right ?
A small explaination would be helpful :)

Comment: You're right : the condition in an if statement should be red as a condition in a while. It continues until the condition becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

`||` won't work as expected here because the for loop condition works the other way. A for loop condition is the same as a while loop condition. The loop breaks when the condition you specify evaluates as `false`. So the way you've specified it, the loop will run *while either* `x < 3 || lenghtCounter == 0`.

I think what you want is:

`x < 3 && lenghtCounter != 0`

or:

`x < 3 && lenghtCounter > 0`.

(Also lenghtCounter a typo?)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need  `|| lenghtCounter==0`. When lengthCounter reaches 0 you call `rs.next()` one extra time, and that's why you're possibly getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess you are trying to not have the inner loop run until the outer loop has run three times.  However, each time the outer loop runs, x is reset to 0 due to scope.  Recheck your scoping - declare x before the loops.

Additionally, your outer loop will do nothing by itself. You may want to switch to a while loop with multiple logic incrementers for x and y.